# Display a div container when hover over menu item using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have read other articles on this and I am wondering what it is that I'm doing wrong.

I have a container I wish to display when a menu item is hovered over. Here is the container.

```
<section class="mega_menu_container">
                    
    <div class="mega_menu_outer">
                            
        <div class="mega_menu_inner">
                            
            Inner MEGA MENU

        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Here is the Menu container

```
<a href="#" class="menu_item1"><div class="menu_item1"><Strong>Item</Strong></div></a>
```

Here is the CSS I am using to control it.

```
.mega_menu_container {
    width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 99999999;
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu_item1:hover + .mega_menu_container {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu_item1{flex-direction: row;}
```

I really have tried with other answers.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Can you please post a *more complete* version of your HTML? What you have supplied is not enough to troubleshoot your code. Your CSS is using the **adjacent sibling** selector `+` which means the `menu_item1` element must **immediately** precede the `mega_menu_container` element as a sibling in your code.

Comment: It is not an adjacent sibling. What part of the code do you need? it is in a different section. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML structure is not clear from the question above, but I guess the problem is that `.mega_menu_container` does not come immediately after `.menu_item1`.

Use `+` only if `.mega_menu_container` comes immediately after `.menu_item1`.

See the snippet below.

```css
.mega_menu_container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999999;
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu_item1:hover + .mega_menu_container {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu_item1 {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_item1">Hover me</div>
<div class="mega_menu_container">Lorem ipsum</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="menu_item1">Hover me - it will not work</div>
<div class="element_inbetween"></div>
<div class="mega_menu_container">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Use `~` if there are other elements between `.mega_menu_container` and `.menu_item1`.

See the snippet below.

```css
.mega_menu_container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999999;
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu_item1:hover ~ .mega_menu_container {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu_item1 {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_item1">Hover me</div>
<div class="element_inbetween"></div>
<div class="mega_menu_container">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

If none of the above works, you need to use JavaScript.

See the snippet below.

```js
var hover_element = document.querySelector('.menu_item1');
var show_element = document.querySelector('.mega_menu_container');

hover_element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  show_element.style.opacity = '1';
});

hover_element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  show_element.style.opacity = '0';
});
```

```css
.mega_menu_container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999999;
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu_item1 {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_item1">Hover me</div>
<div class="mega_menu_container">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: I understand, thank you. Is there a way for me to do the same thing but for a none adjacent sibling. So it could be anywhere on the page? Thank you.

Comment: @JackB There is a **General Sibling** selector `~` which works if the two elements are both siblings (like you see here in **Cervus**'s answer. If they are not contained within the same parent element (and both direct siblings), there is no way to select them in CSS.

Comment: I updated my answer. If this doesn't work, then you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: So I would have to use JS? Could you recommend?

Comment: Yes, see **EDIT 2**.